# How are SQL operations with combined clauses performed on database b-trees

Tags: database, database-design

I get the basic about how B-trees are useful for databases as they guarantee a O(log(n)) insertion/deletion, allow to store data in an orderly manner and are more efficient than binary search tree when retrieving data from disks.

So I think I understand more or less how for example these operations could be performed independently:

```
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY upvotes WHERE upvotes > 100
```

Here I'm guessing the tree keys storing the `posts` records are `upvotes` and so we can find the lower bound `upvotes = 100`. Once we found the node with this key, it's only a matter of traversing the rest of the tree from that point.

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = ?
```

Since the `id` is unique, it's a `find` operation on a tree based on `id` keys.

**Question 1:** So, if this is how it work for the above operations, then **does the database keep a b-tree for every column** so that data in a table record is sorted in every way possible ?

**Question 2:** How would operations with combined clauses be performed, let's say:

```
SELECT * from posts WHERE upvotes > 100 AND downvotes < 5
```

I don't understand how this can be done efficiently.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "*does the database keep a b-tree for every column*" - no. It only "keeps" the indexes you create

Answer (score 0):

These are all going to vary by database vendor.  Assuming some kind of SQL variant:

Question 1 - the DB usually keeps a B-tree of some kind for your PK and any other indexes you explicitly tell it to.  Some other operations may or may not also create an index.  A Unique constraint for example is often implemented by creating an index.  I am not aware of any DB that creates an index on every column by default.

Question 2 - To find the specifics for a given database, check out how you get the query plan then read to documentation.  It usually gives you a pretty good idea.  For example Ssometimes you'll see an index seek followed by a scan and a filter on the residual records.  Sometimes just a table scan is the best (or only) plan.  There are also column stores which provide more options.

It's almost impossible to answer these questions in general.